I lost a Lego piece and sticker
I lost my Lamborghini Countach brick and sticker. The sticker is number 2 and the brick is a white flat 1x4.

Welcome to Bricks SE. We are a question & answer site, but it seems are not asking a question.

You can buy parts and sticker sheets from 3rd party sellers on sites like https://www.bricklink.com/ https://www.brickowl.com/
